# NGINX - return different maintenance pages for each location block

Tags: nginx

Our nginx server serves multiple applications within one server block.  The location blocks for each application are loaded via an include directive (pulls the app specific conf files from a directory) and each application has a separate directory containing their content (via alias).  We would like to have separate maintenance pages for each application that are activated by putting the maintenance.html file in the application specific content directory.

The standard "if (-f ..)" gets it to detect the maintenance.html file, but can't seem to figure out how to have it load/return the specific maintenance.html file for that application without creating separate @maintenance_<appname> location blocks, at the same top level, for every application.  Was hoping there was some way to encapsulate everything the specific app needs into its own specific location block without having to put additional app specific directives at the top level.

Here's our main server block:

```
    server {
        listen       6003;
        server_name  foo101.test.com;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;

        root /u01/app/dev/nginx_content;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        include /u01/app/dev/nginx_content/app_includes_1.24.0/*.conf;

        error_page   500 502 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
.
.
.
}
```

Here's the example application specific include file:

```
#Start of config for fooapp1

location /fooapp1 {
                alias /u01/app/dev/nginx_content/webcontent/fooapp1/;

                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /fooapp1/index.html;

                absolute_redirect off;
                expires max;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, immutable";
                add_header Last-Modified "";
                etag off;
                if_modified_since off;

                location ~ /index.html|.*\.json$ {
                        expires -1;
                        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                }

                if (-f /u01/app/dev/nginx_content/webcontent/fooapp1/maintenance.html) {
                    return 503;
                 }

}

#End of config for fooapp1
```

If I add redirect 503 to an app specific @maintenace at the top level, it seems to work:

server level @maintenace:

```
        location @maintenance_fooapp1 {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /webcontent/fooapp1/maintenance.html break;
        }
```

app include:

```
               error_page 503 @maintenance_fooapp1;    # requires @maintenace_fooapp1 location block at top level (was trying to avoid)
```

But just seems there should be a better way to do it, so that we don't have to generate seperate maint locations for each app.